# Firestore Pagination query on collection group data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

**Description:** I want to implement infinite scroll in React-Native with firebase and i want to paginate on collection group data for instant result in my app. Error is shown in screenshot.

**My code:**

```
var ref = firestore().collectionGroup('user_posts').orderBy('time_stamp', 'desc').limit(5);
    ref.get().then(snapshot => {
      var posts = []
      var lastVisible = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
      this.setState({ last_Visible: lastVisible });
      }); 

var next = firestore().collectionGroup('user_posts').orderBy('time_stamp', 'desc')
          .startAfter(this.state.last_Visible)
          .limit(5);
 next.get()
        .then(FirestoreDocumentSnapshot => {
          var lastVisible = FirestoreDocumentSnapshot.docs[FirestoreDocumentSnapshot.docs.length - 1];
          this.setState({ last_Visible: lastVisible });
})
```

***Please help, what i am doing wrong?***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From a first look at the error and your code it seems like either the fields that you are referring to are empty, or the `lastVisible` should be an even number.

Try checking that you don't have empty fields in your docs and try removing the -1 from `lastVisible`.

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#startAfter(java.lang.Object...)) you can check the proper way to use startAfter() which is the cause of your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But If i try to removing the -1 from lastVisible then it's show undefined because index is start from 0 and if an array have 10 item then 10th item will be at index[9]. [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors?authuser=0) **I am using this documentation**

Comment: have you any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you're sorting by time_stamp, you should specify that field in the query like so:

```js
.startAfter(this.state.last_Visible.data().time_stamp)
```

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) is an example from the official documentation. (From the language tabs choose Node.js)